# Existence of an isomorphism $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n+m}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

There exist an isomorphism of varieties? $$\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n+m}$$

I am considering $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m$ as the product in the category of varieties.

Comment: Are you asking for _any_ pair of positive integers n,m?

Comment: What methods do you allow; can you use, e.g., homology (Kunneth)?

Comment: If you're talking about Real projective space, You can dismiss the cases when one is orientable but the other is not.

Answer (score 7):

I) The varieties  $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$ and $\mathbb P^2$ have subvarieties behaving differently and can thus not be isomorphic:

a) In $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$ there exist two irreducible subvarieties which are are not points but are nevertheless disjoint, namely $\{a\}\times \mathbb P^1$ and $\{b\}\times \mathbb P^1$ for $a\neq b\in \mathbb P^1$.
b) If you take two different irreducible subvarieties $X,Y\subset \mathbb P^2_k$ which are not reduced to points they have non-empty intersection: $X\cap Y\neq \emptyset$.

Assertion b) results from  elementary elimination theory and does not require Bézout's theorem with its subtle notion of intersection multiplicity.  It requires however that $k$ be algebraically closed.

II) If $k$ is not algebraically closed you can go over to an algebraic closure of $k$ but this "change of basis" is generally not studied in elementary algebraic geometry.
 For the non algebraically closed field $k=\mathbb R$ however, the  topological  manifolds  underlying $\mathbb P^{n+m}_\mathbb R$ and  $\mathbb P^n_\mathbb R\times \mathbb P^m_\mathbb R$  are not even homeomorphic, since their fundamental groups are respectively $\mathbb Z/2$ and $\mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/2 $.
So these algebraic varieties are *a fortiori* not isomorphic.

III) For general values of $n,m$ more sophisticated methods are necessary over general fields.
For example one can  use Picard groups: $\text {Pic} (\mathbb P^n\times \mathbb P^m)=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$, whereas $\text {Pic} (\mathbb P^{m+n})=\mathbb Z$

**Edit**
The result  $\text {Pic} (\mathbb P^{m+n})=\mathbb Z$  is  proved in detail in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, Chapter II, Proposition 6.4.
The result  $\text {Pic} (\mathbb P^n\times \mathbb P^m)=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ follows from the  general result of Chapter III, Exercise 12.6, page 292.  See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/493719/3217).
There are probably  more elementary references and I would be grateful to any user who would indicate one.

Comment: Dear Georges, I agree that the Picard group proof is the natural one. But I think the following is more elementary: you can prove the analogue of your statement (b) in $\mathbf{P}^{n+m}$ for any two subvarieties whose dimensions add up to at least $n+m$. This is Hartshorne theorem I.7.2, so it doesn't need very much.

Comment: Dear @Asal, you are quite right: Hartshorne's Theorem I.7.2 is fairly  elementary and gives another proof of the required non-isomorphism. I'll be happy to upvote you if you transform your comment into an answer. Meanwhile, +1 for the comment .

Comment: Dear Georges, thanks for the kind words. But the OP already has plenty of answers, including their own, which seems like it might be the most efficient possible. So I will leave my comment as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

These spaces are not isomorphic, so you won't find an isomorphism.

I'm not sure what the best way to see this is if you don't know much algebraic geometry.  Heuristically, you can note that, topologically, $\mathbb{RP}^1 \times \mathbb{RP}^1$ is a torus, whereas $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is a non-orientable surface, but I guess you could object that that doesn't actually *prove* anything in algebraic geometry...

You can embed $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ via the Segre embedding and compare it to $\mathbb{P}^2$, but that comparison may take more machinery than you're familiar with.

Comment: I know these spaces are not isomorphic... I want an other answer... or maybe the same.

Comment: I don't understand... if you know the spaces are not isomorphic, why are you looking for an isomorphism between them?

Comment: I am not looking for an isomorphism... Exist an '?'... So I am asking.

Comment: "The varieties are not isomorphic" literally means "there does not exist an isomorphism between the varieties."

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think $\mathbb RP^2$ is a sphere; are you sure?

Comment: @DBF, good catch.  I'd written something about the complex case (where $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is a sphere) and changed my mind, but apparently didn't perform the edit cleanly.  $\mathbb{RP}^1$ is of course the basic example of a compact non-orientable surface.

Comment: Dear Daniel, in the last sentence of the above comment you certainly mean $\mathbb RP^2$

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to fix that now, but at least what it now says in the actual answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer ; I'll get to the rest.

If by $\mathbb P $ you refer to the case of Real projective space, then , if both m,n are odd, their sum is even, which cannot happen, since Real projective spaces $\mathbb RP^n$ are orientable iff n is odd; the product of orientable manifolds is orientable, e.g., by Kunneth's theorem, the top homology over the integers is $\mathbb Z$.

You can rule out many other cases where both $m,n$ are even, since then $m+n$ will be even, and, by, e.g., Wikipedia, $H_p (\mathbb P^n(\mathbb R))$ = (over the integers)

1) $\mathbb Z/2$ , for $p<n $ , when p is odd.

2) $\mathbb Z$ , for n , when n is odd

3) $0$ for n, when n is even.

4)$\mathbb Z$ , for $p=0$;

Then, for $m+n$>$k$> $max$ {$n,m$}  and k odd,

We will have $H_k(\mathbb (P^n \times \mathbb P^m, \mathbb Z))= \mathbb Z/2(+)Z/2$ , $\neq$ $H^k(\mathbb P^{n+m}, \mathbb Z )=\mathbb Z/2$ .

So the two are not even homotopically-equivalent , at least most of the time.

Comment: I think he's viewing these as affine varieties over an algebraically closed field in the Zariski topology.

Comment: Ah, thanks; I wish I'd known, save myself some time.