# Computing $H^k(\mathbb{C}P^n \times \mathbb{C}P^m, \mathcal{O}^*(\mathbb{C}P^n \times \mathbb{C}P^m))$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

I have to calculate Cech cohomology groups $H^k(\mathbb{C}P^n \times \mathbb{C}P^m, \mathcal{O}^*(\mathbb{C}P^n \times \mathbb{C}P^m))$, working in Cech cohomology, where $\mathcal{O}^*$ is the sheaf of invertible olomorphic functions. Is there e method using Segre embedding?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493005/picard-group-of-product-of-spaces