# Isomorphism between Projective Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Let $m,n\geq 0$ be integers and $k$ be an algebraically closed field. $\mathbb P^n \times \mathbb P^m$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^{m+n}$ if and only if $m=0$ or $n=0$.

any comments and hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: A clue to the answer can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983568/how-to-show-p1-times-p1-as-projective-variety-by-segre-embedding-is-not-is

Comment: If you don't mind working over the complex numbers in the analytic topology, it's pretty easy to see this by computing the topological cohomology.

Comment: Dear @KReiser: I have some missunderstanding with your answer, first line of your answer is a propositon or can you explain it? I just have some basic knowledge about projectve varieties.

Comment: Dear @Tabes Bridges: I need it to be solved as a variety. Thank you.

Comment: This is a basic fact about projective space - see for instance Hartshorne theorem I.7.2.