# Need a counterexample to show that Cl$(X\times Y)$ is not always same as Cl$(X) \oplus $Cl$(Y)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Recall that for a quasi projective variety $X$ one can define the [Divisor Class Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_(algebraic_geometry)) denoted by $\operatorname{Cl}(X)$.

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ be two quasi projective varieties.What is the counterexample to show that $\operatorname{Cl}(X\times Y)$ is not always same as $\operatorname{Cl}(X) \oplus \operatorname{Cl}(Y)$ ?

I know that the above result hold if one of the $X$ or $Y$ is $\mathbb P^n$ but i dont see any "natural" counterexample in general case.Any ideas?

Comment: Hartshorne IV 4.10 gives an example.

Comment: @AreaMan To be clear, you're referring to an exercise in that section.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Thanks. Specifically, the claim in the exercise is that, for $X$ an elliptic curve, $Pic(X \times X)$ is an extension of the endomorphism ring of $X$ (as an elliptic curve) by $Pic(X) \times Pic(X)$. @hoot

Comment: Cool. I like the mentioned Ex. V.1.6 as well, although I guess it's a little indirect.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/493677/3217) is a nice class of examples

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picard group of product of spaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493005/picard-group-of-product-of-spaces)